# datatype and type in SML not working as intended

Tags: types, sml, smlnj, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to implement a little parsing library based on a [monadic parsing paper](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/monparsing.pdf). I want to do it using SML(NJ), as I am learning about SML.

Here is what I have so far:

```ml
type 'a parse_data = ('a * char list);
type 'a parse_result = 'a parse_data list;

type 'a parser = char list -> 'a parse_data list;

datatype 'a parse_result = ParseFailure
                         | ParseSuccess of 'a parse_result;
```

Then I try to use it as follows:

```ml
ParseSuccess ([("a", [#"a"]), ("b", [#"b"])]: string parse_result);
```

Which gives the following error:

```ml
stdIn:21.15-21.66 Error: expression doesn't match constraint [tycon mismatch]
  expression: (string * char list) list
  constraint: string parse_result
  in expression:
    ("a",#"a" :: nil) :: ("b",#"b" :: nil) :: nil: string parse_result
```

I think this is weird, because I think I have aliased `('a * char list) list` with `'a parse_result` using the `type` declarations already. So I try to dig deeper into the issue and try the following:

```ml
([("a", [#"a"]), ("b", [#"b"])]: string parse_result);
```

Again error, now as expected:

```ml
stdIn:22.2-22.53 Error: expression doesn't match constraint [tycon mismatch]
  expression: (string * char list) list
  constraint: string parse_result
  in expression:
    ("a",#"a" :: nil) :: ("b",#"b" :: nil) :: nil: string parse_result
```

So I tried to define the `datatype` without type aliasing the `parse_result` as follows:

```ml
datatype 'a parse_result = ParseFailure
                         | ParseSuccess of ('a * char list) list;
```

Then suddenly it works:

```ml
([("a", [#"a"]), ("b", [#"b"])]);
val it = [("a",[#"a"]),("b",[#"b"])] : (string * char list) list
- ParseSuccess [("a", [#"a"]), ("b", [#"b"])];
val it = ParseSuccess [("a",[#"a"]),("b",[#"b"])] : string parse_result
```

I do not understand, why it will not accept my type alias `string parse_result` in place of `(string * char list) list`. Shouldn't that work? How else do I define `'a parse_result` to be able to use it instead of `('a * char list) list`?

My SMLNJ version is: `Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Sat Oct 26 12:27:04 2019]`

Comment: Why does the type alias have the same name as the datatype? ?:/

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I must have been blind there, after hours of searching for what could be wrong. Thank you for that! When I change the name, it works. Can you make that into an answer? Is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can answer your own question, as a service to future answer-seekers.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Did that now. Marking as solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake was in the naming of the `datatype`. It has the same name as the `type` defined before it. Once it was renamed, the error went away. Working code is then:

```ml
type 'a parse_data = ('a * char list);
type 'a parse_result = 'a parse_data list;

type 'a parser = char list -> 'a parse_result;

datatype 'a result = ParseFailure
                   | ParseSuccess of 'a parse_result;
```

Comment: Rather than prepending "parse" on names, you may want to wrap this code up in a "Parse" structure.

Comment: I think that's good advice. I still need to learn about structures though. Working through Elements of ML Programming currently and have not learned about them yet : )